# Whats the music that plays in Naruto ep. 48 on 16:10?

Tags: naruto

As said, whats the music that plays on 16:10 in Naruto ep 48, it plays when Gaara gets beaten up, but turns out he was defending himself with a sand shell.

Answer (score 1):

I remember this theme also playing in that one filler episode in Shippuden after the Pain arc where they flash back to Naruto's pre-timeskip days, when he went on a mission with that old eternal genin guy (who makes really good soup) and two other jounin. Anyway, the mission went awry, and the team got chased by enemies. The two jounin stayed back to delay the pursuers, but three of the enemies slipped through and caught up to Naruto and the eternal genin. The eternal genin then did a wavy with his arm and did some kind of willow genjutsu technique. And this theme played when that happened.

This track is an unreleased track. It doesn't show up in Naruto Original Soundtrack I, II, or III.

There are some unofficial, imperfect fan-spliced versions floating around on the interwebs, though. For example, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YoQb3xBVM4), titled "Eerie".